# Android SMS delivered result

Tags: android, sms, report, receiver

I'm developing a SMS app for android. And I want to save the message state (ex, when delivered)

But the receiver returns always a RESULT_OK when sending a SMS. This is the code I'm using:

```
        Main.context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                Main.log("SMS delivered");
                LogThread logThreadEntregado = new LogThread(main, smsId);
                logThreadEntregado.setEntregado();
                Thread t6 = new Thread(logThreadEntregado);
                // t6.run();
                Main.mHandler.post(t6);
                Main.context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Main.log("SMS not delivered");
                LogThread logThreadNoEntregado = new LogThread(main, smsId);
                logThreadNoEntregado.setNoEntregado();
                Thread t7 = new Thread(logThreadNoEntregado);
                Main.mHandler.post(t7);
                Main.context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                // t7.run();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

I want to know if there's a way (maybe with the arguments Context arg0, Intent arg1) to check if the message has been really delivered.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kannel will send you back the delivery reports in the url you specify in the dlr-url parameter in the SMS submission, for example example.com/DLR?outgoing_id=123&status=%d.

What language you write it in is irrelevant. All you need is an HTTP page that accepts specific parameters via HTTP GET. Kannel will add parameters for the delivery status, time, et al, and you will link them to your SMS submission via its id as above.

**[This discussion](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-dlr-mask---dlr-url-p3884418.html)** has a clear example.